# User has Full Control, but can't view List on site

Tags: 2010, list, permissions

Rate Form Owners has Full Control: ![Rate Form Owners][1] 
Dev User3 is part of Rate Form Owners: ![DevUser3-names are blacked out to protect the innocent][2]
This is what they should see: ![Should see][3]  When I select "Rate Form" to open the table pulling the web part, this is what they should see: ![Should see again][4]
BUT, when logged in as Dev User3, a member of Rate Form Owners, with Full Control of this subsite, this is what they see when they try and open the list: ![Access Denied][5]
Here is the uniquely secured content on this subsite: ![Uniquely Secured Content][6] Notice that the All Submissions list is not on here.
Here are the page permissions (inherited from parent): ![Page Permissions][7]
Still other people in the list cannot see  All Submissions.

(images removed)

Comment: Two things to try:

1) Navigate to your 'All Submissions' List, then click 'Check Permissions'. Enter in 'Dev User3' and see what permissions are applied for that user.

2) Use something like fiddler, or developer tools to monitor traffic while logged in as 'Dev User3'. There may be some rendering artifact, like an image, that the user doesn't have access to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I added Rate Form Owners to the permissions for the page (parent), and gave them Read permissions, my Dev User3 was able to view the page.